# OCaml variance (+'a, -'a) and invariance

Tags: ocaml, covariance, contravariance, invariance

After writing this piece of code

```
module type TS = sig
  type +'a t
end
  
module T : TS = struct
  type 'a t = {info : 'a list}
end
```

I realised I needed `info` to be mutable.

I wrote, then :

```
module type TS = sig
  type +'a t
end
  
module T : TS = struct
  type 'a t = {mutable info : 'a list}
end
```

But, surprise,

```
Type declarations do not match:
  type 'a t = { mutable info : 'a list; }
is not included in
  type +'a t
Their variances do not agree.
```

Oh, I remember hearing about *variance*. It was something about *covariance* and *contravariance*. I'm a brave person, I'll find about my problem alone!

I found these two interesting articles ([here](https://blogs.janestreet.com/a-and-a/) and [here](https://ocaml.org/meetings/ocaml/2013/proposals/injectivity.pdf)) and I understood!

I can write

```
module type TS = sig
  type (-'a, +'b) t
end
  
module T : TS = struct
  type ('a, 'b) t = 'a -> 'b
end
```

But then I wondered. How come that *mutable* datatypes are invariant and not just covariant?

I mean, I understand that an `'A list` can be considered as a subtype of an `('A | 'B) list` because my list can't change. Same thing for a function, if I have a function of type `'A | 'B -> 'C` it can be considered as a subtype of a function of type `'A -> 'C | 'D` because if my function can handle `'A` and `'B`'s it can handle only `'A`'s and if I only return `'C`'s I can for sure expect `'C` or `'D`'s (but I'll only get `'C`'s).

But for an array? If I have an `'A array` I can't consider it as a an `('A | 'B) array` because if I modify an element in the array putting a `'B` then my array type is wrong because it truly is an `('A | 'B) array` and not an `'A array` anymore. But what about a `('A | 'B) array` as an `'A array`. Yes, it would be strange because my array can contain `'B` but strangely I thought it was the same as a function. Maybe, in the end, I didn't understand everything but I wanted to put my thoughts on it here because it took me long to understand it.

**TL;DR** :

> persistent : `+'a`
>
> functions : `-'a`
>
> mutable : invariant (`'a`) ? Why can't I force it to be `-'a` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think that the easiest explanation is that a mutable value has two intrinsic operations: getter and setter, that are expressed using field access and field set syntaxes:

```
type 'a t = {mutable data : 'a}

let x = {data = 42}

(* getter *)
x.data

(* setter *)
x.data <- 56
```

Getter has a type `'a t -> 'a`, where `'a` type variable occurs on the right-hand side (so it imposes a covariance constraint), and the setter has type `'a t -> 'a -> unit` where the type variable occurs to the left of the arrow, that imposes a contravariant constraint. So, we have a type that is both covariant and contravariant, that means that type variable `'a` is invariant.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I expected so this post can help future OCaml developers to understand easily and rapidly this variance matter.

Comment: I think you meant “and the *setter* as type …” — submitted an edit, hope I didn't get the fix wrong! Really stumbled over that for a few minutes.

Comment: yeah, definitely :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your type `t` basically allows two operations: getting and setting. Informally, getting has type `'a t -> 'a list` and setting has type `'a t -> 'a list -> unit`. Combined, `'a` occurs both in a positive and in a negative position.

[EDIT: The following is a (hopefully) clearer version of what I wrote in the first place. I consider it superior, so I deleted the previous version.]

I will try to make it more explicit. Suppose `sub` is a proper subtype of `super` and `witness` is some value of type `super` which is not a value of type `sub`. Now let `f : sub -> unit` be some function which fails on the value `witness`. Type safety is there to ensure that `witness` is never passed to `f`. I will show by example that type safety fails if one is allowed to either treat `sub t` as a subtype of `super t`, or the other way around.

```
let v_super = ({ info = [witness]; } : super t) in
let v_sub = ( v_super : sub t ) in   (* Suppose this was allowed. *)
List.map f v_sub.info   (* Equivalent to f witness. Woops. *)
```

So treating `super t` as a subtype of `sub t` cannot be allowed. This shows covariance, which you already knew. Now for contravariance.

```
let v_sub = ({ info = []; } : sub t) in
let v_super = ( v_sub : super t ) in  (* Suppose this was allowed. *)
v_super.info <- [witness];
   (* As v_sub and v_super are the same thing,
      we have v_sub.info=[witness] once more. *)
List.map f v_sub.info   (* Woops again. *)
```

So, treating `sub t` as a subtype of `super t` cannot be allowed either, showing contravariance. Together, `'a t` is invariant.

Comment: Well, your answer is like the unrolling of ivg's answer but it's a nice addition ;-)